# parameter estimation using chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, fitting

I want to understand how to use chi-square statistic to estimate parameters. It would be appreciated, if you could comment on my reasonings here.

When I have data from 1 million measurements and expect that the data follow Poisson distribution. The problem is to find a good Poisson mean, $\mu$. Below is a plot showing my data and models. The models are determined by assumptions about the Poisson mean. The histograms for the models were generated by 1 million simulations.

- Although some bins are expected to have zero counts, chi-square goodness of fit is applicable. One can simply ignore the bins with zero counts.
- After calculating $\chi^{2}$ for the two models, the p-values corresponding to the $\chi^{2}$ values indicate if each of the model can be rejected. For example, a p-value of 0.01 can reject a model.
- The p-values can be compared to find a better model. Equivalently, a smaller $\chi^{2}$ means a better model. One can scan over a various parameter values and achieve a good fitting by find the one resulting in the minimum $\chi^{2}$.

[image: plot]

Comment: If you have a Poisson distribution, all bins should have an expectation for a nonzero count.   Just because you *observe* a zero count doesn't mean you should exclude it.

Comment: @jbowman depending on a certain Poisson mean, number of trials, and the number of bins, the expected counts in a bin can be smaller than 5. Then that bin should be excluded, isn't this correct?

Comment: That's a different issue than your first bullet point above, which is what I was addressing.  However, if you are trying to minimize the $\chi^2$ statistic as the objective function in a parameter estimation procedure, you don't want to exclude anything.

Comment: @jbowman Then is it possible to estimate the parameters by minimizing $\chi^{2}$, given those data?

Comment: Sure, issues such as multicollinearity or an unidentifiable model aside.  But... if you do so, you shouldn't then use the $\chi^2$ statistic in a (standard0 goodness of fit type test, because you've picked the one most likely to reject the test, whereas tests usually assume the statistic hasn't been chosen with such an objective.  There are ways of working around this, but it is something to be wary of.